# Is there a way to automatically click on a link every time a specific website loads in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I'm using a database type website where there is one link I have to click on alot. It opens in a new tab.

Is there some way that I can auto click a link in that new tab, the link it clicks closes the tab, then wait for that specific website link/tab to appear again then click that link again.

I'm using Chrome with Windows 10, Any help would be appreciated.  The website that loads in a new tab is always the same URL with just that last 4 digits changed and the link I want clicked is always the same link in same location.

Comment: I'm not following what you're trying to do.  Are you trying to pin links? Why open a link in a new tab and close the old tab; why not just open the new link in that tab?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried any browser automation tools like [kantu browser automation](https://a9t9.com/kantu)

> Kantu is a modern Selenium IDE plus tons of additional features,
>   open-source Record and replay web macros with this free and
>   open-source Chrome and Firefox extension for web browser automation.
>   The extension is an easy to use web macro recorder for web developers,
>   web testers and especially for general web automation and form
>   filling.

You can create macros that will do exactly as you want - open a link(you can select the link on page using the product's selector tool) then add another step for a delay/wait for page to load and then click a link on that page. it is pretty simple to use and they have detailed tutorials and a robust community forum

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/802299)

Comment: Can you expand your answer a bit? Just pointing to a product doesn't really explain how to accomplish the solution, and it's often viewed as spam. It's better to include some instructions on how to use the product to solve the problem, or at least describe what makes the product a good solution, providing value beyond a random Google hit. Good guidance on recommending software here: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers.  Thanks.

Comment: is this better @Peterh